# Login form in iframe from AliExpress doesn't work in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, forms, phantomjs, dom-events, form-submit

I'm trying to login to AliExpress through PhantomJS, but my script doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

I'm using PhantomJS Version 2.0.0.

The login form is inside an iframe, maybe that's the problem.

This is the code:

```
var page = new WebPage(), step = 0, loadInProgress = false, timeOut = false;
var url = 'https://login.aliexpress.com/buyer.htm?spm=2114.11040108.1000002.7.8yVuzJ&return=http%3A%2F%2Fcl.aliexpress.com%2F';
```

Function to fill and submit the form inside the i-frame.

```
var sendForm = function(){
    var iframeRef = function( frameRef ) {
        return frameRef.contentWindow
            ? frameRef.contentWindow.document
            : frameRef.contentDocument;
    };

    var iframe = iframeRef(document.getElementById('alibaba-login-box'));
    var arr = iframe.getElementById('login-form');
    arr.elements["fm-login-id"].value="my-email";
    arr.elements["fm-login-password"].value="my-password";
    iframe.getElementById('login-form').submit();
    console.log("Form submitted.");
};
```

These are the steps that my program follows:

```
var onFinishedSteps = [
    //Opens the web to log-in.
    function(){
        page.open(url);
    },
    //Fills the form and submits it.
    function(){
        page.render('0before fill.png');
        page.evaluate(sendForm);
        page.render('1just after submit.png');
    },
    //Renders the web ~10 seconds after submitting.
    function(){
        console.log("timeout setted");
        timeOut = true;
        window.setTimeout(
            function () {
                console.log("timeout function");
                page.render('2timeout.png');
                timeOut = false;
            },
            10000 // wait 5,000ms (5s)
        );
    }
];
```

First the web page is loaded, then the form is filled and submitted (and rendered).
This two steps works fine. The rendered images shows the filled inputs (email and password) and the i-frame content properly.

The third step should give the program enough time to process the form and login, but the rendered image still shows the form, this time with the password input empty and no message (like 'incorrect password' or something like that).

This is the rest of the program:

```
page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
    console.log('Trying to navigate to: ' + url);
    console.log('Caused by: ' + type);
    console.log('Will actually navigate: ' + willNavigate);
    console.log('Sent from the page\'s main frame: ' + main);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
};

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    loadInProgress = false;
};

interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && typeof onFinishedSteps[step] == "function") {
        console.log("----------------------- Step " + (step + 1));
        onFinishedSteps[step]();
        step++;
    }
    if (!loadInProgress &&  !timeOut && typeof onFinishedSteps[step] != "function") {
        console.log("test complete!");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}, 50);
```

Here is a link with the complete file if you want to test it.
Github: https://github.com/xAlstrat/PhantomJsFunctions/blob/master/aliexlogin.js

Comment: You really should add `&&  !timeOut` to both if conditions and not just one of them.

Comment: I'm using the version 2.0.0. I have updated the code with these events, but the program shows no errors. And you're right with the boolean condition, thanks !
I've added a link to the whole code in the question description.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you cannot call a function on an element in a different frame (iframe). There are a couple of things you can try.

- Run PhantomJS with the `--web-security=false` commandline option:

  ```
  phantomjs --web-security=false script.js
  ```
- Change into the frame context before trying to do something in it. You can use [`page.switchToFrame()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-frame.html) or other similar functions to change into the frame context by name or frame index. For example:

  ```
  page.switchToFrame(1); // Try this out
  page.evaluate(function(){
      var arr = document.getElementById('login-form');
      arr.elements["fm-login-id"].value="my-email";
      arr.elements["fm-login-password"].value="my-password";
      document.getElementById('login-form').submit();
      console.log("Form submitted.");
  });
  ```

  This produces a synthetic submit event.
- You can trigger a native submit event by triggering an enter keypress with the [`page.sendEvent()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) function. For example like this with the previous suggestion:

  ```
  page.switchToFrame(1); // Try this out
  page.evaluate(function(){
      var arr = document.getElementById('login-form');
      arr.elements["fm-login-id"].value="my-email";
      arr.elements["fm-login-password"].value="my-password";
      arr.elements["fm-login-password"].focus();
  });
  page.sendEvent("keypress", page.event.key.Enter);
  ```
- Maybe you even need to "type" both username and password as native events into the fields, because simply setting the field values doesn't trigger any events that might be registered on those elements. Which might trigger validation which might be necessary to have run before the form can be submitted:

  ```
  page.switchToFrame(1); // Try this out

  page.evaluate(function(){
      document.getElementById("fm-login-id").focus();
  });
  page.sendEvent("keypress", "my-email");

  page.evaluate(function(){
      document.getElementById("fm-login-password").focus();
  });
  page.sendEvent("keypress", "my-password");

  page.evaluate(function(){
      document.getElementById("fm-login-password").focus();
  });
  page.sendEvent("keypress", page.event.key.Enter); // or page.event.key.Return
  ```

Comment: Hi ! I've  tried all those things, but it still it doesn't work properly, just a little bit different. Using the 'Return' event instead of 'click()' or 'submit()' it seems to work better. Now, after  the return event, a captcha appears below the password input. I think it is a kind of security system because I dont get any captcha using a common browser like chrome.

Comment: The CAPTCHA is specifically there to prevent you from doing what you're trying to do. There is really nothing easy that you can do to solve this besides displaying the CAPTCHA to a user somehow and let them solve it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The problem was solved using the return event, but I'll have to use another approach for this problem.